# Convert type 'Emgu.CV.Mat' to 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>'

Tags: c#, emgucv

I was trying to convert `Emgu.CV.Mat` to `Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, byte>` in EmguCV using `Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(mat.Bitmap);` as I used to do, but I found that it was removed in the current version 4.5.1.4349.

What is the current alternative to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found another way to do it, it seems to be in previous releases and still working.

```
Image = mat.ToImage<Bgr, Byte>();
```